# How can I get the genesis block info

Tags: genesis

I am playing around with a private blockchain, and I realize that I do not know how to get the "genesis block" info. The eth.getBlock(0) does not show the Genesis information, for example, pre-fund by "alloc".

So, how can I retrieve the information of the Genesis block?

My Genesis file looks like:

```
  "gasLimit": "0x30000000",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "e9722f81388f8f99771cad2770aba1f4b9e2d86c": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
```

What I want to know is how can I get the "alloc" information through the web3 or JSON-RPC API.

Comment: Do you mean the genesis block of the mainnet or of your private chain?

Comment: My private chain. I have the Genesis file. What makes me confused is I think the information should have been written into the block, but I do not know how to get the information (for example, through web3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the public networks, those values are defined in a config file. For geth you can find those values in this file (for mainnet, and testnets)

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/config.go#L33

regarding a private network, well you need a genesis file to initialize your network, so you should have it somewhere. However, it is possible to reverse engineer most values. Give a look at the rpc methods:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

for example, from your javascript console (`$ geth attach "http://localhost:8545"`) calling

```
> net.version
```

will return you the networkId

```
> eth.getBlock('latest')
```

will return you the latest block from which you can find the `gasLimit`, etc

Comment: How to get the "alloc" information? How to get the address and balance in "alloc"?

Comment: I dont think you can using RPC methods. Browsing `https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/genesis.go` it looks that the alloc addresses and balances are saved in geth DB. What makes sense since it is **required** to have a genesis file to `init` a node. Therefore all node will know about the alloc info. The info being saved in the node DB it is for sure possible to recover them. Nevertheless I dont have an answer on how to do it